# Django translation makemessages missing #. in .po file

Tags: django, localization, translation, django-i18n

I'm experiencing syntax error when i run `manage.py compilemessages`. I opened the .po file and found out that some line doesn't have `#:` at the beginning of the line. he translation code was implemented correctly in the source file. It was replaced with a space. I've checked the source file's translation code and it was implemented correctly.  What is causing this?  Thanks in advance!

Expected line code:
`#: .\source\of\the\file.py`

Actual line code:
`.\source\of\the\file.py`

source file:

```
class Region(AbstractOrganization):

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        help_text=_("The name of the region")
    )

    slug = AutoSlugField(
        populate_from=['name'],
    )

    region_group = models.ForeignKey(
        RegionGroup,
        verbose_name=_("Region Group"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='regions',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    country = models.ManyToManyField(
        Country,
        verbose_name=_("Country"),
        related_name='regions',
        through='M2MRegionCountry',
        blank=False,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Region')
        ordering = ('region_group', 'name',)
```

Comment: Would you like to show the relevant code (where you mark for translation)? Also how do you run the command `makemessages`?

Comment: @nik_m i run it inside my app, not the same level as manage.py

Comment: So the translations that lack `#: ` are from the above class `Region`?